# Matlab : How to convert my image data to idx3-ubyte?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, image-scaling

l'm working with mnist dataset which has a format of idx3-ubyte. Now, l have created my own image dataset and l want to put them in the format of idx3-ubyte. How can l do that.

My images are formated as mnist 28*28 under the extension of png.

Thanks for your helps